# Django I want to subtract two dates like start_date - end_date and want only days

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

**view.py** code:

```
def applied_leaves(request):
data = All_Leaves.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)
dayss = [i.end_date.date() - i.start_date.date() for i in data]

print("dayss",dayss)

return render(request, 'applied_leaves.html',{"leaves_data":data,"days":dayss})

print("dayss",dayss)
```

output:

[datetime.timedelta(3)]

but I want to get only 3 because of its days how to remove `datetime.timedelta`?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: did you tried `dayss = [(i.end_date.date() - i.start_date.date()).days for i in data]`

Comment: Hey Deniz Kaplan, Thanku so much for kind help its works.yeaaaahh !

Comment: I posted it as an answer with a link to timedelta part, you may mark as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get `days` attribute from `timedelta` object.

```
dayss = [(i.end_date.date() - i.start_date.date()).days for i in data]
```

For more information, you can read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

Comment: hi, i want to add start date end date in subtract result how could i do that?

Comment: Couldn't understand what you expect to get. Can you write the expression that didn't work? You can add/subtract two timedelta objects. There are some examples of supported operations on the docs link above.